# how to make text move below the JQuery slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a JQuery toggle/slide type menu and would like the text below to move when the JQuery slides down.

As I am new to this, my code will probably be messy. I apologise for this in advance, but it is almost working the way I need it to.

please see the code in action [here](http://chadi.rhpmgroup.com.au/criminal_charges/testjquery.html)

Comment: Just wrap the text in a wrapper element that is positioned relative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's happening because you're floating the two sliders, taking them out of the normal document flow. You could do this to the content below it:

```
<article>
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <h3>Vestibulum tortor quam</h3>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante.  </p>
</article>
```

And then prevent it from allowing floats around it with CSS:

```
article{
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just place the text in its own `div`

```
<div id="textId">
    <!-- text elements here -->
</div>
```

Then use the following css

```
#textId {
    float: left;
    position: relative; 
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a  around you content underneath the menus.

Then add a class to the div with the following css:

```
clear: both;
```

edit: exactly, after the #sliderright div and before starting the Criminal Charges element, put a

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have issues with closing the `<ul>` element, you reopen it:

This:

```
<ul>
    <li>Possession or use of Firearm without Licence Permit</li>
    <li>Unregistered Firearm</li>
    <li>Not keep Firearm Safe</li>
    <li>Discharge Firearm</li>
<ul>
```

Should be:

```
<ul>
    <li>Possession or use of Firearm without Licence Permit</li>
    <li>Unregistered Firearm</li>
    <li>Not keep Firearm Safe</li>
    <li>Discharge Firearm</li>
</ul>
```

Then clear the div floats:

[Here is a working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/dAeD5/)

Comment: Thanks for picking up un the <ul> not closed properly, didn't pick that up my self.lol